TensorBoard can’t find your event files.Log directory: s3://bucketname/tensorboard_log/

tensorflow version:
tensorboard 2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.8.1
tensorflow 2.11.0
tensorflow-addons 0.19.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.11.0
tensorflow-io 0.34.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.34.0
tensorflow-serving-api 2.11.0
runcmd：
tensorboard --logdir s3://bucketname/tensorboard_log/
Environment Variable:
AWS_REGION='us-east-1'
S3_REGION='us-east-1'
S3_ENDPOINT='10...129:610**'
S3_USE_HTTPS=0
S3_VERIFY_SSL=0
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***
No dashboards are active for the current data set.
Probable causes:
You haven’t written any data to your event files.
TensorBoard can’t find your event files.
If you’re new to using TensorBoard, and want to find out how to add data and set up your event files, check out the README and perhaps the TensorBoard tutorial.
If you think TensorBoard is configured properly, please see the section of the README devoted to missing data problems and consider filing an issue on GitHub.
Last reload: Apr 16, 2024, 5:40:35 PM
Log directory: s3://bucketname/tensorboard_log/
Read minio logs correctly


